# How to deploy react client to azure from visual studio 2017

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, azure

I have one project with asp.net core server and another project (which one supposed to be nodejs for azure server, but I don't need server part) with my react (cra) app. I want to be able run npm install and npm run build every time before publishing. For now, I solve this problem by using post build action. But this runs only if files is out of date. Changes in folder with my react app is not enough for visual studio to rebuild. So i need to manually run rebuild every time I want to publish changes in my react app. Is there more correct way to publish react app separated from backend, from visual studio to folder on aws?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the same as you were upload any other app is very simple.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2017

Comment: But this i way it wouldn’t run npm build and just will publish this as static files.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up automatic deployment from a Github repo. I have it set up so that everytime I push code to the master-branch on my Github-repo it rebuilds my app and publishes it.

Here's a guide on how to do it: https://blog.github.com/2015-09-15-automating-code-deployment-with-github-and-azure/

If I'm honest, I find this approach to be easier than having to publish manually. Also, all I need is Git.